# How to create C# delegate double callable like this `f(a + k * h)`?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, delegates, function-pointers

I have created a `public delegate double DynamicFunc(double x);`

and now I try to create an instance of it to pass into a component later

```
    private DynamicFunc f(double x)
    {
        return (return_ => x);
    }
```

But when I do stuff alike this:

```
double value = 2 * f(50);
```

I get: Error    Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'DynamicFunc';

Why - what is wrong with my deligate?

Comment: On first glance you seem to have a wrong return type

Answer (score 2):

Calling function f with any sort of argument returns a dynamic function, not a value you can use in a math expression..

```
private DynamicFunc f(double x)
{
    return (return_ => x);
}

double value = 2 * f(50)();
```

However, have you considered this alternative? That way you need no delegate:

```
private Func<double> f(double x)
{
    return (() => return x;);
}

double value = 2 * f(50)();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the existing Func delegate :

```
Func<double, double> f = new Func<double, double>(x => x);
double value = 2 * f(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `f` function returns a delegate (`DynamicFunc`). You need to invoke this delegate by passing it a double argument in order to get the result:

```
double value = 2 * f(50)(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because f() is declared to return a delegate and not a double.

You should declare f like this:

```
private double f(double x)
{
    return (return_ => x);
}
```

Then in a call:

```
private double SomeFunc(DyanmicFunc func)
{
    return 2 * func(50);
}
```

And call it with:

```
double result = SomeFunc(f);
```